# How to recover data from NTFS partition after accidently running EXT4 dd on it?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, dd

I was trying to copy my EXT4 partition as backup and I accidentally putted my NTFS partition containing my data on the dd command.

Now my data is lost :(

I've tried testdisk but it wasn't able to find partition. What should I do?

Update: This was the command I ran:

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sda1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: Exactly what did tou run? Please update your question with the command you did run.

Comment: @SorenA this is what I ran dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sda1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync

Comment: What is overwritten is gone. dd copies data from source (if=) to destination (of=) and overwrites data on destination. Testdisk can only recover data that hasn't been overwritten. A current backup is your only hope now.

Comment: Is there any way to recover what can be recovered by repairing the filesystem?

Comment: No! `dd`copies block for block and overwrites the destination - what is overwritten is gone.

Comment: so there's no way to revert the disk table and recover what wasn't overwritten?

Comment: This command overwrites sda1 with the full content in sda2, so you don't have a chance.